# Use conditional inside filter() in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like ot use conditional inside a filter() function in vuejs, but i got an error after `|| if`

This is my code :

```js
return this.produits.filter((item) => {
  return (
    item.codeproduct == this.codebar ||
    if (item.produitbrand) {
      for (let i = 0; i < item.produitbrand.length; i++) {
        if (item.produitbrand[i].brandsubproduit) {
          for (let e = 0; e < item.produitbrand[i].brandsubproduit[e].length; e++) {
            item.produitbrand[i].brandsubproduit[e].codeproduct == this.codebar
          }
        }
      }
    });
})
```

Any orientation ? Thank you.

Update : This is my error :
[image: Error message]

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: what is the error msg?

Comment: Thank you for ur reactivity, i updated post for you

Comment: `if` is a [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements). You cannot use it with `||` as part of an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `if` and `for` statements are not allowed inside an expression.

`return (` starts an expression.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, this is how you should write it:

```js
return this.produits.filter((item) => {
  if (item.codeproduct == this.codebar) {
    return true;
  } 
  if (item.produitbrand) {
    for (let i = 0; i < item.produitbrand.length; i++) {         
      if (item.produitbrand[i].brandsubproduit) {
        for (let e = 0; e < item.produitbrand[i].brandsubproduit.length; e++) {         
          if (item.produitbrand[i].brandsubproduit[e].codeproduct == this.codebar) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

It is really matter of style, but this is how *I* would write it:

```js
return this.produits.filter(item => {
  if (item.codeproduct == this.codebar) return true;
  for (let { brandsubproduit } of item.produitbrand || [])
    for (let { codeproduct } of brandsubproduit || [])
      if (codeproduct == this.codebar) return true;
  return false;
});
```